# How to Handle BQ GA Export Changes?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to reprocess ga_sessions_yyyymmdd data but am finding the ga_sessions never used to have a field called [channelGrouping] but it does in more recent data.

So my jobs work fine for the latest version of ga_sessions but when i try reprocess earleir ga_sessions data the job fails as it's missing the [channelGrouping] field.

Obviously usually this is what you want, but in this case it's not. I want to make sure i'm sticking to the latest ga_sessions schema and would like the job to just set missing cols to null for when they did not exist.

Is there any way around this?

Perhaps i need to make an empty table called ga_sessions_template_latest and union it on to whatever ga_sessions_ daily table i'm handling - maybe this will 'upgrade' the old ga_sessions to the new structure.

Attached is a screenshot of exactly what i mean (my union idea will actually be horrible due to nested fields in ga_sessions). [image]

Comment: Try to transcript the SQL Legacy to SQL Query, the second one was recomended by Google when happens something like this before. Look for more information on :
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/
This was the tread where the schema fails
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654768/how-to-handle-bq-ga-export-changes

Answer (score 1):

I don't have such a script yet. But since the tables are under your project you are able to update them. You can write a script and update the schema on all tables with missing columns from the most recent schema set.

- I envision a script that gets most recent table schema.
- Then goes back one by one to past tables, does a compare, identifies the missing columns, defines them as not required and nullable, and reads the schema + applies the additional columns and runs the update on the table. Data won't be modified, you will have just additional columns with null values.

you can try out for some also from the Web UI.